# Issues in Viewport Shading

Tags: 3d-view

I am having a city model. However, the issue is when the file is opened in Solid mode, the model is working fine but when the model is opened in Material preview mode or Rendered view mode the model is showing some display issues.
Both the screenshots of Solid view mode & Material preview mode are attached.[image]

Comment: Try going into the material properties for one of the materials (the "tree leaves" for example) and see what the Blend Mode is set to. If it set to alpha-blend, try enabling/disabling _backface culling_ and/or _show backface_ (alpha-hashed and alpha-clip will only have the _backface culling_ option).

Comment: to add to Christopher's comment, try the Opaque setting instead of Alpha Blend

Comment: Thanks Christopher Bennett and moonboots. Your suggestions worked and my problem is solved now.